# Integrating Google Analytics with Salesforce

Tags: integration, google

I want to integrate google Analytics with salesforce so we can have a better understanding of the data we have there.

I searched for some info around the net but all i found was 3rd party apps and  this tutorial :
[Integrating SF with GA](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/integrate-salesforce-and-google-analytics)

But maybe its my misunderstanding about all this but I find that article a bit ambiguous and lacking some details, just in the first step, it says to create this fields, but doesn't say where.

Someone here managed to do what i try to accomplish , if so could someone give me some guidance? Would be nice to know the right path to go.

Comment: I believe the fields you're referring to are on the Lead object. This article outlines pretty well how to get GA data into form submissions, but this may not address what you're trying to accomplish.

When you say "so we can have a better understanding of the data we have there", it doesn't really define the use case. 

GA has a ton of data and it needs to be very clear what you want and where it should be. Integrating directly with the Reporting API - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/ is possible but some of this data is not appropriate for Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, actually my team hasn't specified much about the data i have to get besides it's about the leads and campaigns. Anyway i will talk to the GA specialist so i can know better what are all the data they want to get and which can be retrieved.

Comment: If you are looking to pull GA stats into SFDC, I might be able to point you in the right direction - I have some code that logs into GA via oAuth, then retrieves page analytics for all the URLs on site/subsite - let me know. The GA API explorer is helpful with that as well

Comment: Yeah, i would be totally interested in having a look at that code, it would be really useful. Within the next days i will contact to the GA specialist so we can work together into making this improvements so if you can show me some of the code you did that would be really helpful. 


Thanks.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC, I'm looking to pull GA stats into SFDC. If you can share your code that will be really helpful. Thanks.